# where is jquery_rails javascript files located in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've read the documentation on the asset pipeline.  It says assets will be looked up in the 3 asset locations and compiled into the public folder, but I don't see any javascript in any of the 3 locations in the new rails project that I have just created.  I have run bundle install and the jquery rails gems is installed.  But grep for "jquery" gives no such file.  Where is jquery located?

Answer (score 1):

They're located [within the gem itself](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts).

Comment: that's counter-intuitive... how do I know which version of jquery it is using?  And how will i update it in the future?

Comment: The top of each file has a comment with the version number. Whenever they update the version of jQuery in the gem you can update the version of the gem you're using in your app. If you don't like it you can always just include jQuery manually instead.

Comment: from the console in your favourite browser you can also just query

    `jQuery.fn.jquery` to get the version